# What is this component of a TV called?

Tags: components, tv

I am getting a burning plastic smell from the behind vents where this component is located. What is this component?

Better quality image here: https://prnt.sc/rarfs6

[image]

EDIT: The TV in the picture is not mine - it's a video from Youtube with the same TV model.

Comment: Offtopic: I always wonder do they put electrolytic capacitors just next to the heat sinks on purpose...

Comment: The red arrow points to a connector. In my opinion, if you did not know this already you should not even be opening your TV. Repairing TVs is best left to professionals. There are dangerous voltages inside a TV.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks for the suggestion, it's not my tv, I found a youtube video with the same model being opened. What is the component in the middle that the connector connects to the power supply (power supply is on the left?)?

Comment: That connector probably connects to output of the **flyback converter SMPS** to the LEDs in the backlight. Get a service manual (with schematics) of the TV, link it in here and we can have a look. If you cannot explain what a "flyback converter" does then you should not open the TV and have a professional repair it for you.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I can't seem to find a service manual, but the model is Sony KD55XF9005. I don't plan to fix it myself, I already took it to the warranty, and they said they couldn't find the issue. I plan to take it back to them again, and I would like to be able to tell them what I suspect, since they don't seem to be interested in finding the issue themselves.

Comment: For the strong burning smell to show up, the TV needs to run for a few hours with sound on and some HD video content playing, I suspect they didn't do that at the warranty and thus didn't find the issue or the smell.

Comment: Realistically they're going to ignore what you think is wrong, unfortunately - your best hope is leaning on your refund or replacement rights, possibly via the credit card you bought the thing on. If you want to open it up up and remove the metal cover, you may or may not spot something brown and discolored causing the smell - but that of course interferes with the warranty claim.

Comment: Let it run for some days until it fails completely. Then ask for warranty again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is not techincal one (at least so far). As Bimpelrekkie said, you must not open your TV and try to disassemble it further or fix it - you simply risk to void the warranty, and will get charged if service center finds it out.

Your problem is in business area, particularly in safety. The smell from electronics is not  a regular mode of its operation. Smell usually leads to fire and injuries. Negligence in this respect is not tolerated.

If your TV has already been brought to the service center, you must have some proof of it. The next step would be to apply to the management of the service center with written claim that your TV is a safety threat, and get their receipt that they have been notified about it.

Next step will be to apply to the local representative office of the manufacturer (Sony).

The abovementioned actions can be performed without visiting the locations, through email, with further visit on agreed time.

You may also make a shortcut writing to the social media, it may speed up the resolution if you do it properly, but may involve you into the unpleasant and negative conversations publicly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The disassembled tv is not mine - it's from a video on Youtube. I am not going to disassemle the device. Do you maybe have a guess what the component is?

Comment: TV is under warranty, and I would not much care about what it is. Talk to the service engineer on occasion to get this info if you are really interested.

Answer (score 2):

In a new device some odor is not unusual, if it makes smoke that is unusual.

The brown board is the power supply

The green board is the tuner, mixer, and embedded computer.

The grey module is the LCD driver

Smell is probably not a fault that can be remedied under warranty,
wait until it starts misbehaving.

Comment: The smell hasn't disappeared and has possibly gotten worse in 4,5 months. It's not a smell of a new device, it's smell of toxic, burning plastic.